# There is no wifi icon at top right and i cant connect to internet

Tags: wireless, internet

i've been trying for ages and i cant connect to internet. Its really odd because there is no option to connect wireless for me. At the top right there is no wifi icon or anything. Even when i use the lshw -C network command, it says some stuff about ethernet but i use a usb wifi adapter. please help me get the internet.

Comment: Please provide your OS/flavor/release details.   Did you try any of suggestions found in https://help.ubuntu.com/community/WifiDocs/WirelessTroubleShootingGuide where the *device recognition and operation* will be the most useful (it'll help you to find out what you have so you can use search engines, or tell us so we can help you).

Comment: What model is your usb wifi adapter? Some might not be compatible with Linux.

Comment: My adapter is a "Wifi N" and i am not using a mac, im using a windows

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -knn | grep Net -A3; rfkill list` terminal command.

Answer (score 0):

Check the wifi settings to see if the laptop even detects that you have a network adapter. If not detected, try restarting your laptop and entering BIOS settings. Leave BIOS settings and start you computer again. For me this was often enough to get my laptop to detect my networking card again.

Comment: Does ubuntu work on windows since i am using windows. Also when i go into network settings it doesnt show wifi, it shows wired. When i go to wifi settings it says No wifi adapter found. also i went into BIOS but it didnt work